# Angular material table sticky header not working properly

Tags: css, angular-material, sticky

Video of issue: https://www.veed.io/view/f5e3234c-b8b1-4488-aeb1-93ea831a898d?panel=share

Table header is set to sticky but it is being hidden upon scrolling down the table body.

Sorry I am unable to share the whole code. Basically I set the table header to

```
th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

but it is not working as it should. In the video you can see the table body, when scrolled down, hides the header that's supposed to be sticky. I checked possible culprits like overflow value in any ancestor and there's none. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Have your read the docs on the `mat-table`? You're not supposed to manually add `position: sticky`, but use the `sticky` directive on your `matHeaderRowDef`. See the docs [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sticky-rows-and-columns) , and provided examples [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples). Not much else can be said until you reproduce the issue on stackblitz.